# Python: Unable to import mechanize module on Mac

Tags: python, mechanize, macports, easy-install

I have mechanize module installed using easy_install but when I tried to import I get the following error:

```
Python 2.6.7 (r267:88850, Nov 21 2011, 14:59:21) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import mechanize
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named mechanize
```

Just to confirm that I have installed mechanize I did easy_install again and it confirm  that I have mechanize:

```
easy_install mechanize
Searching for mechanize
Best match: mechanize 0.2.5
Processing mechanize-0.2.5-py2.6.egg
mechanize 0.2.5 is already the active version in easy-install.pth

Using /Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/mechanize-0.2.5-py2.6.egg
Processing dependencies for mechanize
Finished processing dependencies for mechanize
```

I realize that not only mechanize most of the external modules that I install using easy_install don't get available for import. Is it due to the fact that I have macports installed..?

This is what I get from `echo $PATH`
echo $PATH

```
/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/Users/N-H/DevApps/android-sdk-mac_x86/platform-tools:/Users/N-H/DevApps/android-sdk-mac_x86/tools:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/opt/subversion/bin/:/opt/subversion/bin:/usr/bin/java:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin:/Users/N-H/DevApps/android-sdk-mac_86/tools:/Library/grails-1.3.6/bin:/opt/subversion/bin:/usr/bin/java:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin:/Users/N-H/DevApps/android-sdk-mac_86/tools:/usr/bin/gcc-4.2
```

I did which python and looks like mac ports installs python under opt directory... (not really sure)

```
$which python
/opt/local/bin/python
```

Comment: why this was mark negative..?

Comment: I was wondering the same thing.

Comment: Maybe it installed the module in a different directory than Python expects? I'm not familiar with its resolution of modules process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you have installed mechanize to python 2.6 provided with Os X, but you are running python interpreter installed from macports.

You can run easy_install for python from macports with (for python 2.7):

```
/opt/local/bin/easy_install-2.7
```

Comment: brilliant thanks what would be the mac port command to set default python version as 2.7 I am on 2.6

Comment: IIRC it is  "sudo port select python python27"